# Can't set a cookie w/ Nuxt.js, Express-Session

Tags: express, vuex, express-session, nuxt.js

I'm new to NUXT and SSR and I've been researching this for a few hours now and I can't seem to figure it out. I'm using JWT to authenticate users in my Nuxt app with a Bearer Token, which is working great until I hit refresh and lose my session.

Now I'm looking to persist sessions using express-session and connect-mongo. I can't get the cookie to set on the client to be included on future requests.

When a user is authenticated:

```
router.post('/login', function(req, res) {
  User.findOne({
    username: req.body.username
  }, function(err, user) {
    if (err) throw err;

    if (!user) {
      res.status(401).send({success: false, msg: 'Authentication failed. User not found.'});
    } else {
      // check if password matches
      user.comparePassword(req.body.password, function (err, isMatch) {
        if (isMatch && !err) {
          // if user is found and password is right create a token
          var token = jwt.sign(user.toJSON(), config.secret, { expiresIn: 604800 });
          req.session.authUser = { 'user': 'Test User' }
          return res.json({success: true, token: token, user: user});
        } else {
          res.status(401).send({success: false, msg: 'Authentication failed. Wrong password.'});
        }
      });
    }
```

The console.log above shows the authUser in the session.

```
Session {
  cookie: 
   { path: '/',
     _expires: 2018-04-03T18:13:53.209Z,
     originalMaxAge: 60000,
     httpOnly: true },
  authUser: { user: 'Test User' } }
```

When I look at my chrome devtools application cookies a connect.ssid hasn't been set and when I console.log(req.session) on future requests the authUser is missing.

My server code is:

```
// Passport 
var passport = require('passport');
var passportJWT = require("passport-jwt");
var ExtractJwt = passportJWT.ExtractJwt;
var JwtStrategy = passportJWT.Strategy;

// Config File
let config = require('./config/settings.js')

// Initialize Express
var app = express();

// CORS-ENABLE
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://127.0.0.1:1337");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", 'true');
  next();
});
app.use(cors())

const dbPath = 'mongodb://blogUser:blogUserPassword@localhost:27017/blog'

// Express Session
app.use(session({
  secret: 'super-secret-key',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  store: new MongoStore({ url: dbPath }),
  cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }
}))

// File Upload
app.use(fileUpload());

// view engine setup
// app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
// app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Routes
var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
app.use('/api', index);
app.use('/users', users);

// Passport Config
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session())

// mongoose
const options = {
  autoIndex: true, // Don't build indexes
  reconnectTries: Number.MAX_VALUE, // Never stop trying to reconnect
  reconnectInterval: 500, // Reconnect every 500ms
  poolSize: 10, // Maintain up to 10 socket connections
  // If not connected, return errors immediately rather than waiting for reconnect
  bufferMaxEntries: 0
};

console.log(options);

// Localhost Connect
mongoose.connect(dbPath, options).then(
  () => { console.log("connected !!!"); },
  err => { console.log(err);  }
);
```

Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: you can try this example : https://github.com/ahadyekta/nuxt-auth-external-jwt

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the server you create the problem with the session is the express router, because change res and req vars so like recommend in nuxt use this.

```
const express = require('express');

// Create express router
const router = express.Router()

// Transform req & res to have the same API as express
const app = express()
router.use((req, res, next) => {
  Object.setPrototypeOf(req, app.request)
  Object.setPrototypeOf(res, app.response)
  req.res = res
  res.req = req
  next()
})
```

Comment: _If you want to use the server you create the problem with the session is the express router, because change res and req vars so like recommend in nuxt use this._ the sentence doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing this step

```
// Create express router
const router = express.Router()

// Transform req & res to have the same API as express
// So we can use res.status() & res.json()
router.use((req, res, next) => {
  Object.setPrototypeOf(req, app.request)
  Object.setPrototypeOf(res, app.response)
  req.res = res
  res.req = req
  next()
})
```

The req, res parameters need to be interchanged on the client side

Once you do router.post('/login') and logout

```
app.use('/api', router)
```

And that will work perfectly